# Django - How to filter using a ManyToManyField field?

Tags: django, django-models

**Models**:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    options = models.ManyToManyField(Option, blank=True)

class Option(models.Model):
    ...

class ProductVariant(models.Model):
    ...
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE) # parent product
    option = models.ForeignKey(Option, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True)
```

I need to find all the `ProductVariant`s where the `option` doesn't belong to any `options` on the parent product `Product`.

I tried doing the following filtering:

```
ProductVariant.objects.exclude(option_id__in=[o.pk for o in F('product__options')])
```

But I got the following exception:

```
'F' object is not iterable
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try filtering by `Count` instead:

```
ProductVariant.objects.annotate(product_count=Count('option__product')).filter(product_count=0)
```